# Change the Product version of exe file into Jenkins pipeline

Tags: .net, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, version

I have a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline for my .Net application and I would like to change the product version in each stage. For example: in the Staging stage,  I would like to set the product version to "1.0.0.STG" and when the PRE-PROD stage is executed, change the Product Version to "1.0.0.PRE-PROD". Should I build it again in each stage?

Comment: What are you referring here? Means you want to change the artifact version built in each stage within Jenkins workspace? OR do you generally mean to replace the value for PRODUCT-VERSION variable in each stage of your Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Let me explain you. In the AssamblyInfo.cs I set the `AssemblyInformationalVersion`(Product Version) to "1.0.0". These version is showed in the tilte of my winform application. When the pipeline build is done,in the next step I deploy the artifacts to integration server and I would like to show in the form title "1.0.0.STG". Is it possible from the CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: I was thinking to modify the Product Version in each stage an build it again but I don´t know if there is another approach

Comment: You can change the version to anything you like during the jenkins build.

Comment: You can set the PRODUCT Version as a build parameter to build artifacts with different product versions and download it as required.

Comment: but the AssamblyInfo.cs is code, then I need change version and build again before deploy?

Comment: Yes. Rebuild with a new version and deploy.